# Library tooling - hooking into `webpack --watch`

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, webpack-watch

I have a build step (a hook) that needs to happen after webpack --watch finishes. Has anyone had success hooking into webpack --watch to determine when it has completed?

In other words it would like this:

1. start `webpack --watch` in the background
2. file(s) change, `webpack --watch` creates a new build
3. run some hook after `webpack` completes the rebuild

does anyone know a good way of doing this?

Comment: I filed a related issue on the Webpack Github issue tracker - https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5895

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I think will be to use the [`webpack-shell-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-shell-plugin) plugin. It allows you to run any shell commands before or after webpack builds. Just install it with `npm install --save-dev webpack-shell-plugin` and edit your `webpack.config.js`:

```
const WebpackShellPlugin = require('webpack-shell-plugin');

module.exports = {
  ...
  ...
  plugins: [
    new WebpackShellPlugin({onBuildStart:['echo "Webpack Start"'], onBuildEnd:['echo "Webpack End"']})
  ],
  ...
}
```

Review plugin docs for a more info.

Comment: thanks, I filed a related issue on the Webpack issue tracker - https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5895, maybe that will give you more context...but I think your answer might work